# Create dynamic questionnaire from web service .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, forms, dynamic

i just want to know, which do you think would be the best aproach to do this. I am consuming a web service who gives me the questions, the posible anwsers and the correct anwser, and what i have to do is validate the anwsers from the user. But if i just create the form on the init event, in order to .net to see the created controls for validating i need to recreate the controls in postback, but i can't do that because the webservice would give me another questionnaire. Is it okay to store the questionnaire on a cache object and rebuild the controls from there? What do you think? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the question and the answers in the viewstate or session.

Comment: Yes, i guess cache, session or viewstate would do the trick, but i was waiting for a blowmind anwser.

Comment: @Agorilla - Don't know how to make a blowmind answer :). Cache is not a good option as it is shared between all the pages/users. Session is per user, but if application pool is recycled, then you would lose the session. I recommend viewstate, as it is per page. In this case this will be the most scalable and robust solution.

Comment: Yes you are right, i would use viewstate. Maybe there isn't any better way of doing it. Thanks!